# React native failing path resolution - using former directory name

Tags: reactjs, react-native

While trying to solve another problem (inadvertently over-wrote /constants/index.js without realizing it), I re-named the `constants` directory `constants2`. After restoring `index.js`, I changed the directory name back to `constants`.

Now, when RN resolves the path to /constants/Layout.js, it's throwing

> undefined is not an object (evaluating '_constants2/default.tabBarHeight')
>    Changing the name back to constants2 doesn't help.

I have followed all of the instructions for clearing caches (`npm` and `yarn`), including deleting the temp cache directory. I have searched the contents of the files in my project and in the cache directory for the string `constants2` and nothing found. I have upgraded everything possible.

I'm at wit's end. Where could this old path be stored?? I renamed the directory within `Atom` and I'm wondering if that might be the source of the trouble. Platform is `Windows 10`.

Comment: are you sure there is no `constants2` refers in your file?

Comment: "I have searched the contents of the files in my project and in the cache directory for the string "constants2" and nothing found." Something unclear about that?

Comment: you don't have to be defensive. I _was_ trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this, but I'm not sure why.

I changed this:

```
import Layout from '../constants';
import Colors from '../constants';
import Images from '../constants';
```

To this:

```
import { Colors, Images, Layout } from '../constants';
```

and the problem went away. Shouldn't either one have worked? And I still can't see why it was still referencing the former path.

Comment: No, `import Layout from '../constants';` is not the same as `import { Layout } from '../constants';`